# warning: narrowing conversion of 'tempo' from 'int' to 'unsigned char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing] heres my code

Tags: arduino, project

This code is for a Instrument cluster to link to ets2 but i keep getting an error like warning: narrowing conversion of 'tempo' from 'int' to 'unsigned char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

```
 if (tempo > 1) {
          //KMH aktualisieren
          for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            unsigned char stmp[] = {1,128,tempo,0,0,0,0,0};
            CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x5A0, 0, 8, stmp);
            delay(10);
            }
            }
            /*
            //Wenn Nadel auf 0 geht, KMH neu schreiben
            FreqCounter::f_comp= 8;             // Kompensation einstellen
            FreqCounter::start(100);           // Zähler starten für 1000ms
            while (FreqCounter::f_ready == 0)   // warten bis der Zähler fertig ist
            freq=FreqCounter::f_freq;           // Ergebnis lesen
            freq=freq*10; 
            
            */           
          else{
            unsigned char stmp[] = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x5A0, 0, 8, stmp);
            }
```

Comment: "Warning" <> "Error".

Comment: The warning is telling you what's going on: `tempo` is an `int` (16-bits for Arduino ATmega328), and you're trying to store it in a `uchar` (8-bits). The compiler is telling you it doesn't fit and it chopped the 16bit value to 8bits. If you know `tempo` only ranges from 0 to 255, then it's probably safe to ignore the warning. Otherwise you have to re-design - maybe send high and low halves of the int16 if the tempo really goes that high, or the hundreds and the tens+units (123 bpm -> 1, 23). I don't know what the receiver expects, so maybe this isn't possible.